# BLI_assert failed edge_hash

Tags: python, import

I use the following python script that imports a stl, modifies it and exports the modified stl in a Docker container running Ubuntu 18.04 and Blender 2.79:

```
import bpy
import os
import sys

if len(sys.argv) < 8:
    print("Usage: blender --background [optional args here, for example -noaudio] --python stl2safety_distance.py -- safety_distance_in_m input_path/file_name output_path/file_name")
else:
    input_file = sys.argv[len(sys.argv) - 2] + ".stl"
    if os.path.isfile(input_file):
        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
        bpy.ops.object.delete()
        bpy.ops.import_mesh.stl(filepath=input_file)
        bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
        bpy.ops.mesh.extrude_region_shrink_fatten(TRANSFORM_OT_shrink_fatten={"value":-1.0 * float(sys.argv[len(sys.argv) - 3])})
        bpy.ops.export_mesh.stl(filepath=sys.argv[len(sys.argv) - 1] + ".stl", ascii=True)
    else:
        print("Input file does no exist: {}".format(input_file))
        raise
```

The stl is exported as expected, however I get the following output (even multiple times) in my terminal:

```
blender(BLI_system_backtrace+0x33) [0x56400a4a7fb3]
 blender(BLI_edgehash_lookup+0xfd) [0x56400a46591d]
 blender(BKE_mesh_calc_edges+0x226) [0x56400a208cf6]
 blender(ED_mesh_update+0x57) [0x564009caaa27]
 blender(RNA_function_call+0x12) [0x56400a3174a2]
 blender(+0x14c4fbd) [0x564009e73fbd]
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(_PyObject_FastCallKeywords+0xd3) [0x7f20086c1043]
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x2f33) [0x7f20084bcd53]
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(+0x794d3) [0x7f20084c44d3]
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x7b95) [0x7f20084c19b5]
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(+0x794d3) [0x7f20084c44d3]
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x7b95) [0x7f20084c19b5]
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalCodeWithName+0x996) [0x7f20085e91e6]
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(_PyFunction_FastCallDict+0xae) [0x7f20086c030e]
 blender(+0x14c5907) [0x564009e74907]
 blender(+0x1a6ffa6) [0x56400a41efa6]
 blender(+0x109c79e) [0x564009a4b79e]
 blender(WM_operator_call_py+0x6b) [0x564009a4c11b]
 blender(+0x14d0f5a) [0x564009e7ff5a]
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(_PyMethodDef_RawFastCallKeywords+0x2f9) [0x7f20086bfcc9]
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(_PyCFunction_FastCallKeywords+0x25) [0x7f20086c0a05]
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x8bde) [0x7f20084c29fe]
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalCodeWithName+0x996) [0x7f20085e91e6]
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(_PyFunction_FastCallDict+0x1c3) [0x7f20086c0423]
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(_PyObject_Call_Prepend+0xcd) [0x7f20086c320d]
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(+0x215c35) [0x7f2008660c35]
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(_PyObject_FastCallKeywords+0xd3) [0x7f20086c1043]
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x2f33) [0x7f20084bcd53]
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalCodeWithName+0x996) [0x7f20085e91e6]
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x3e) [0x7f20085e946e]
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCode+0x1b) [0x7f20085ea23b]
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(PyRun_FileExFlags+0xb2) [0x7f20085b7e52]
 blender(+0x14bb515) [0x564009e6a515]
 blender(+0x1092c82) [0x564009a41c82]
 blender(BLI_argsParse+0xd6) [0x56400a4542e6]
 blender(main+0x264) [0x564009a093e4]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xeb) [0x7f20035b909b]
 blender(_start+0x2a) [0x564009a405ca]
 BLI_assert failed: /build/blender-X0i0N1/blender-2.79.b+dfsg0/source/blender/blenlib/intern/edgehash.c:95, edgehash_bucket_index(), at 'v0 < v1'
```

Do you have any idea what might cause this `BLI_assert`? What does `edgehash_bucket_index(), at 'v0 < v1'` mean?

Any help is highly appreciated :)

Comment: Based on old reports, the input file could be corrupted or it's a bug in that version of Blender. You could check if a newer version of Blender doesn't have this issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Indeed this is bug in Blender v2.79. After upgrading to v2.82 the output disappeared.